# PowerShell How to redirect output to another Powershell screen

Tags: c#, powershell, stream, output

I need to be able to redirect some custom output from a current PowerShell screen (which you could see this has workflow) to another PowerShell screen that would be child of the first one (parent)

Note** redirecting to a file is not an option because it must be "live"

So I wonder if it could be simply done in PowerShell or something like opening stream to child PowerShell process in C#.

Thank you

Comment: You could log to a file and then view that file live in a log viewer. My favorite log viewer is [LogExpert](http://www.log-expert.de/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to write directly to another console window.

Your best bet may be to create a script that watches for changes to an environment variable of your creation.

You could then launch this script in a new console window using either Start-Process, Invoke-Item, or some other method (there are several ways to do this).

Alternatively you could create a UI element using WPF or a browser window rather than a second console.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at Powershell Jobs (help about_Jobs)?

Answer (score 0):

Found something interesting 
http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/16998-howto-create-windows-form-without-stopping-script-processing.html

still require some fine tuning but seams to work

```
#
# Create the form - I simplified this a bit and eliminated some unnecessary complexity
#

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$dForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$dForm.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size @(640,480)
$dForm.BackColor = 'Black'
$dForm.Text = "Debug Information"
$dText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$dText.BackColor = 'Black'
$dText.ForeColor = 'red'
$dText.ScrollBars = "both"
$dText.Dock = "fill"
$dText.Multiline = $true
$dText.Parent = $dForm
$dText.ReadOnly = $true
$dForm.Add_Shown({$dform.Activate()})

#
# Create the new runspace
#
$rs = [Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$rs.Open()

# pass in the form object...

$rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("dForm", $dForm)

# and set up a synchronized data interchange object
# between the two runspaces...

$data = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{text=""})
$rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("data", $data)

# Start the pipeline so the form will display...

$p = $rs.CreatePipeline({ [void] $dForm.ShowDialog()})
$p.Input.Close()
$p.InvokeAsync()

#
# Utility routine to show the text. This routine
# puts the text to display into the shared synchronized
# object then calls invoke. It may be that the form
# is not actually ready so it traps this errors and the retrys after a delay...
function Add-TextToWindow()
{
    PARAM(
    [parameter( Position=0, Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage = "Require String name as value ", ValueFromPipeline = $True )] 
    [String] 
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    $text
    )

    $data.text = $text
    [eventhandler]$eh = { $this.AppendText($data.text) }
    #$data.text

    do
    {
        $retry = @($false)
        trap [InvalidOperationException]
        {
            start-sleep -Milliseconds 100
            $retry[0] = $true
            continue
        }
        $dText.Invoke($eh, ($dText, [eventargs]::empty))
    }
    while($retry[0])
}

#
# Now loop for a while writing out some text...
#
#Add-TextToWindow "The date is $(get-date)`n"
#1..30 | %{ Add-TextToWindow "Some text $_`n"; start-sleep -milli 100 }
#Add-TextToWindow "The date is $(get-date)`n"
start-sleep 2

$dForm.Close()
$rs.Close()
```